# How does the legal system operate for dowry death in india?

Tags: india, marriage, murder

Some article on dowry death in india.
[dowry death](https://www.globalcitizen.org/en/content/india-dowry-death-gender-inequality/)

More than 7,600 women were killed or moved to suicide in 2015 as a result of dowry harassment by their husbands or families-in-law, according to India’s National Crime Records Bureau.

Let's have a discussion on kill(murder) instead of suicide.India is the world’s largest democracy,if a greedy husband killed his wife just for dowry ,will he be published to death?Every man punished to death ,the dowry death will disappear,why so many dowry death prevail in india?what happened to the husband's action?How does the legal system operate for dowry death in india?

Comment: Not to be too tongue in cheek, but mostly, the legal system doesn't work when it comes to addressing these cases in India.

Answer (score 1):

### it doesn’t

Murder is illegal in India and a murderer is not entitled to inherit from their victim. That’s the law.

In many cases, the law is not enforced.

Law is a reflection of culture and, where the culture and the law is misaligned, the law is often ignored or otherwise perverted. Unfortunately, Indian culture remains highly mysogonistic and many crimes with female victims including murder and rape are simply not enforced.

Just like many laws in many countries that require genders, races, etc. to be treated equally are not enforced.

The law in India is sound. The culture needs to change. Having laws that reflect the culture a country *wants* rather than the culture they *have* impart of shifting the culture but it is insufficient on its own.

Comment: Below is a so long sentence in your post that i can't understand it,could you rewrite it with more simple way?

Comment: Having laws that reflect the culture a country wants rather than the culture they have impart of shifting the culture but it is insufficient on its own.